# In flash my "AS Linkage" names contains a dot and flash wont recognize them when I use getDefinitionByName

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

My problem is the following:

I imported 1200 .mp3 files for a flash game where the name is "a" + index + ".mp3", for example a0.mp3, a1.mp3 ,(...) then I used  the option to make the "AS linkage" equal to the Name of the file, so far so good but now when I'm trying to access the play the audio by using the  new (getDefinitionByName("a"+ index +".mp3") as Class) it gives the error "ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable mp3 is not defined.". This happens because it contains a dot! I dont wanna go through 1200 files and remove the dot manually, how do I solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you've copied and pasted your code exactly? I ask because there's no issue with adding a period (dot) to an AS Linkage identifier. I ran a test by creating a symbol with the AS Linkage of `Testing.test` and I was able to add it to the stage using `addChild(new (getDefinitionByName("Testing.test") as Class));` with no errors.

Comment: Examples:new (getDefinitionByName("a0.mp3") as Class) -> I get Error #1065: Variable mp3 is not defined.  If  new (getDefinitionByName("a0.mp3.x") as Class) then the error is Error #1065: Variable x is not defined. It only read the names after the final dot. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Maybe this is a flash player version issue. What version are you targeting? I'm publishing to 11.7

Comment: Its version 12.0. I think the dots are used for paths...

Comment: By the way is there any way to change the AS linkage with code?

Comment: While periods are used for "dot notation" (i.e. parent.child.grandChild), they can also be used for AS Linkage identifiers. 

There is no way to change the AS Linkage with code. Try posting a screencap of the properties window of one of your symbols, maybe something will jump out at a second pair of eyes.

Comment: I solved with with a JSFL file! Thanks all for the help.